# Create list of document libraries (duplicate Quick Launch/Libraries)

Tags: 2010, list, document-library

Instead of displaying the Quick Launch "Libraries", I want to display links to the library pages in a list/webpart within the main content section of the page. That way I can include a button/workflow to request permission to a particular library instead of the user navigating to the permission groups if they don't have access.

Forget the button/workflow portion... how do I get a list of all my document libraries? I'm new to SharePoint but I feel this should be straight forward. After all, they are displayed in the Quick Launch, Libraries, and All Site Content pages.

Comment: There's not a way to dynamically identify all libraries in a site. You can write custom code to do this. I work with JQuery the most, and SPServices would let you do this. I think you could also do it with C#.

Answer (score 1):

I am new to SharePoint as well and only have access to SP 2007 so hopefully this answer helps.

I had to come up with a banner of links similar to what your asking so I used a Summary Links Web Part and created 3 columns of links.  I was then able to export that webpart and use it as a template for other pages.

You could also make this a single column with multiple headers to kind of duplicate the quick launch menu.

Hope that helps.